# Bounced Check and ADA

Tags: united-states, civil-law, banking, disabilities

Assume a documented dyslexic person writes a check and transposes two numbers.  The error is such that it results in a bounced check.  Can that person use the Disabilities Act to collect damages from any fees the bank imposes?  What are the chances of success of such action?

On the one hand it seems to be akin to not having a building being wheelchair accessible.  On the other, most banks have a clear path to avoiding high overdraft fees.

Answer (score 2):

There are currently two areas where persons with dyslexia are entitled to special consideration: [education](http://idea.ed.gov/explore/view/p/%2Croot%2Cstatute%2CI%2CA%2C602%2C), and [labor](https://www.dol.gov/odep/pubs/misc/job.htm). Theoretically, one might pursue a claim under [42 USC 12182](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/12182), but at present, dyslexia is not legally on a par with race or religion.